# What would be the best way to create buttons in React

Tags: reactjs

What would be the appropriate way to creating buttons in a react project. For instance, having a create button and edit button where they differ only in the symbol they have (one a plus symbol and the other an edit symbol)

What I would like to do is create a button component that has all the styling I want for it and pass in as props what it is suppose to do? Is this okay to do or not?

I know I can use css or a library like bootstrap for styling but I was hoping I can just create this styling using react only. Thing is that these buttons should obviously do different things for instance a login button and register button make requests but to different api endpoints so is it okay to use the same button component for both? If so how would this actually be done. I can see that I can pass in as props for instance in this case `login` which would be true if the user is trying to login otherwise false. Then in my button component I would make requests to log in.

However, if I were trying to register than `login` should be false and I send request to register instead. This is where I believe my logic is wrong because the button can also maybe do something else besides login and register so how can I do this.

Comment: You should post question and put some minimum code to let reader understand your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done and you can refer this post - https://www.twilio.com/blog/intro-custom-button-component-typescript-react

Basically you can create a custom button component like below -

```
export const Button = (props) => {
 return (
   <>
    {props.symbol === "plus" && <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" />}
    <button onClick={props.onClick} />
   </>
  );
}
```

Then you can simply import this button and pass props to it. You can also add css to the respective icon elements.

Answer (score 0):

As far I was able to understand the questions you wanted to create several buttons which have different appearances and perform different tasks let assume `onClick` you want to perform different tasks like register/login & you are not clear to make make it a single component will that be fine.

Yes, as far as my experience is concerned that is considered to be the standard approach to created buttons eg. in any big project there may be hundreds of buttons used, we can't create them one be one, making a custom **react component** will be the best option, now back to your question how can we perform different tasks for different buttons, I think you already answer that **Props!!**, just pass an appropriate **callback** in **props** for the different instance of **Component** you create(Do consider default values for props)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking but doesn't that mean I would have a button with props where I would have to check if this then that. However, if I did this I feel I would have a bunch conditions checking my props. Imagine I had (login, register, update profile, update note, delete node, delete profile, etc...). This part is what I am wondering.

Comment: @MichaelTorres by using components for buttons, I didn't mean to create only a single component let's assume for 50 buttons, you can categorize(assume 10) all your buttons & created custom button components to make sure code reusability & maintainability. Now let's assume another case if we write them without breaking them into components, we will end up with redundant code in our project also with time/increase in your codebase you might have to add more buttons then it will be difficult to maintain a project. I hope I was able to address your concern

Comment: yes, it does. Thanks After looking at some of the solutions and advice people wrote here and coupling that with some of my own research I believe I am reusing components properly now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to create a button component and pass props and handle click event from button.

## parentComponent.jsx

```
import ButtonComponent from '../..';

export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

handleClick = (type, action) => {
     if(type){  // <=== handle action
     }
 }

render(){
    return (
         <ButtonComponent buttonClass="edit" onButtonClick={(event) => 
            this.handleClick('edit', event)}/>
          <ButtonComponent buttonClass="create" onButtonClick={(event) => 
            this.handleClick('create', event)}/>
    )
  }  
}
```

## buttonComponent.jsx

```
export default class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {



render(){
    return (
         <button className={this.props.buttonClass} type="button" 
             onClick= {(e) => this.props.onButtonClick(
              {
               type: 'edit',
                data:  data 
              }
            )}/>
    )
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In any project usually I keep the buttons and other related components in a component directory. for example Information dialog, error dialog, warnings, modals, buttons, common hooks all such components should be common in the app. below I'm pasting a simple basic app-icon component. Which shows the Icon title and text.

```
type AppIconProps = {
    icon: React.ReactElement
    title: string
    text: string
}

export const AppIcon: React.FC<AppIconProps> = ({ icon, title, text }) => {
    return (
                <List disablePadding>
                    <ListItem disableGutters alignItems="flex-start">
                        <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={title} />
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItemText secondary={text} />
                </List>
    )
}
```

Similarly you can do like this to create a button component having similar styles and you can pass title and icon to the component.